# Time Series Cross Sectional Analysis and Forecasting With R

Tags: time-series, cross-section

cty          time   tl

Argentina   2009_Q4 3

Argentina   2010_Q1 2

Argentina   2010_Q2 7

Argentina   2010_Q3 7

Argentina   2010_Q4 10

Argentina   2011_Q1 7

Argentina   2011_Q2 7

Argentina   2011_Q3 1

Argentina   2011_Q4 7

Argentina   2012_Q1 5

The data set has around 40 countries with each country having quarterly data for 5 years. As I am new to R, can someone assist me with how to perform a cross sectional time series ARIMA/ARMA models etc. and forecast in R? Some basic codes to prepare the data, to perform analysis and forecast for this series as an example would be helpful.

Comment: I would say that 20 observations is not so much for time series analysis. How about using some form of panel regression?

Comment: I think you understood it wrong. I have in total (40 countries * 5years * 4 quartes) observations. But still can you please elaborate on the Panel Regression? I only have column "tl" as the only data row. I mean what will I regress on?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and the answers there were quite helpful. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910450/for-loop-for-forecasting-several-datasets-at-once-in-r).

I would summarise it here for you. If your dataset is called `df` and you want to forecast for each of the 40 countries separately, then you can do so by using either of the packages- `dplyr` or `data.table` along with `forecast`:

`library(dplyr)
 library(forecast)
 model_fits <- group_by(df, cty) %>% do(fit=auto.arima(.$tl))`

OR

`library(data.table)
 library(forecast)
 temp <- setDT(temp)[, list(AR = list(auto.arima(tl))), by = cty]`

Comment: Thank you for you kind response Shraddha! What if I dont want to use auto.arima? I want to fit model by each country and then forecast also by each country. Do I have to write any loop for that?

Comment: May be I don't completely understand what you asked, but if you do not want to use auto.arima and want to be able to manually play around with the AR, I and MA terms and do it for each country, I don't really see a way to fit it in for loop..moreover, auto.arima does that for you anyway by checking AIC levels and selecting the best model of all..

Comment: have you looked into the hts package in R? If your dataset has hierarchical structure then that might be useful..